# Chrome won't open localhost

Tags: google-chrome

I have a web server running in my computer and both Firefox and Internet Explorer will open

```
http://localhost:8080/login.html
```

without any problems but Chrome displays:

```
This webpage is not available
```

Why might this be?

Everything else is fine with Chrome, actually I am accessing stackoverflow using Chrome. only localhost...

incognito window behaves the same.

Comment: What about other pages ?

Comment: @Defoncesko Everything is fine except localhost.

Comment: Ok this problem come from http://localhost:8080 not from http://localhost:8080/login.html ?

Comment: Does it open in an incognito window?

Comment: @JaneGoodall No, incognito window behaves the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with 127.0.0.1:8080/login.html

Comment: I'm not sure but some browsers don't recognize "localhost".

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you cannot make calls to a server that is not included in the permissions section of your manifest. The permissions section of manifest.json should look something like this:

```
  "permissions": [
   "http://myapp.appspot.com/*",
    "http://localhost/*" ]
```

Comment: Where can I find this file?